# Phonegap record audio iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

Hi I just wondered if anyone had managed to get the iphone4 to record audio using phonegap.

I tried the example phonegap provides but was unsuccessful.

Thank you for your time

Kyle

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The [example](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord) for PhoneGap 1.0.0 works fine for me on iOS 4.x.  One catch when using the simulator at least is that the filename you record to should start `documents://`.